# How to install, missing Intel Graphic Drivers

Tags: drivers, video, graphics, intel

I have intel graphics card on my system (Scientific Linux 6.0), but the graphics is so poor as no drivers are installed.
So I have installed :

> xorg-x11-drv-intel-2.21.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64
>   xorg-x11-drv-intel-devel-2.21.2-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64

And Updated for dependencies:

> xorg-x11-drv-synaptics-1.6.2-13.el6.x86_64
>   xorg-x11-server-common-1.13.0-23.sl6.x86_64
>   xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.13.0-23.sl6.x86_64
>   pixman-0.26.2-5.1.el6_5.x86_64
>   mtdev-1.1.2-5.el6.x86_64

But now my system graphics is not starting. It is perfectly working in `init 3`.
I have also changed the kernel parameters while booting:
Added `nomodeset` and `i915.modeset=0`, but the problem remains same.

**Update 1:** As per suggestion of @slm, the output of `lshw` is as below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Sandy Bridge Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fe000000-fe3fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff(prefetchable) ioport:f000(size=64)
[root@localhost ~]#
```

The configuration part only contains `configuration: latency=0`, that means the driver part is missing, what I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

To debug this further we'd need to know which Intel video card you have. You can determine this using the command `lshw`.

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:41 memory:f2000000-f23fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
```

Notice the `configuration:...` line? It tells you which driver is being used. You're probably just needing to configure the drivers that you installed to get things working.

Comment: Take a look at the issue tracker for ELRepo: [0000137: Support of SandyBridge CPU and associated graphics and I/O in EL6 / Kernel 2.6.38.xx](http://elrepo.org/bugs/view.php?id=137). If you're truly on SL 6.0 you'll need to move up to 6.1+ to get this to work.

Comment: Sorry, But once upgrading SL 6.0 to SL 6.2 created problem in my system, and I don't want to take risk now. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Tejas - upgrading the kernel to a newer version. That's what that ticket said, the issue was the version of the drivers + kernel.